# Как в декорируемом объекте использовать метод измененный в декораторе?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, проектирование, декоратор

Приведу простой пример:
Есть класс Coffee, с методами getCost и getCheck().
Метод getCheck выглядит как-то так: `return "Цена заказа: " . $this->getCost();`
Есть множество декораторов вида WithMilk, WithSugar и тд.
Например метод getCost() класс Coffee: `return 100;`.
Метод getCost() класса WithMilk `return $this->coffee->getCost() + 50;`.
Метод getCost() класса WithSugar `return $this->coffee->getCost() + 10;`.
Метод getCheck во всех декораторах: `return $this->coffee->getCheck()`;
Вот такой клиентский код:

```
$offer = new WithMilk(new WithSugar(new Coffee()));
echo $offer->getCheck();
echo $offer->getCost();
```

Такой код возвращает строку `"Цена заказа: 100"`, а хотелось бы `"Цена заказа 160"`.
Но метод getCost() отрабатывает верно. Показывает 160.
Выходит так, что метод getCheck() внутри себя использует метод getPrice() декорируемого объекта.
Дублировать код метода getCheck() внутри декораторов тоже не вариант, т.к. getCheck может отличаться у дукорируемых объектов.

Может быть я не к месту применяю Декоратор? Но создавать кучу классов вида CoffeeWithMilkAndWithSugar тоже не хочу.
Как мне решить эту проблему?

Comment: ищи глупую ошибку в коде/в деталях синтаксиса языка... структурно всё правильно и должно возвращать `160`... в качестве альтернативы могу предложить сделать сахар/кофе «добавками», а в «кофе» завести массив с ними... если у «добавок» и «кофе» будет общий родительский класс, то это будет классический компоновщик — логически он тут ИМХО больше подходит...

Comment: Ошибки в коде нет. Все логично и понятно почему сейчас не работает. По поводу компоновщика хорошая идея, попробую

Comment: да... просмотрел... `getCheck()` просто должен выглядеть как `return "Цена заказа: " . $this->getCost();` в базовом классе и не переопределяться в декораторах.... ЗЫ: что это всё же за язык? или это псевдокод?

Comment: _Как в декорируемом объекте использовать метод измененный в декораторе?_ - никак, декорируемый объект не знает о том, что он во что-то обернут

Comment: @Fat-Zer, скорее всего php, но в данном случае от языка это не зависит

Comment: @Fat-Zer пишу на PHP

Comment: @Grundy но я ведь вызываю метод getCheck() у декоратора и он отрабатывает не верно, хотя с методом getCost() все четко. Получается, что с декоратором нужно работать аккуратно. И реализовать Декоратор для класса использующего "Шаблонный метод" не выйдет

Comment: @ДмитрийМатвиенко, почему ты думаешь, что он отрабатывает неверно? :-) ты вызываешь этот метод у базового объекта никак не меняя, вот и получаешь результат аналогичный вызову сразу из базового объекта

Comment: @Grundy Я имею ввиду неверно, т.е. не так как я хочу. Если бы я использовал наследование, то при изменении в дочернем классе метода getCost() менялся бы результат и метода getCheck(). Я бы хотел так же и при использовании декоратора

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105394/discussion-between-grundy-and--).